# Associative array index as variable

Tags: php

Please i want to use an associative array  values as another array index as like as that.

```
foreach ($array1 as $arr1)
{
    foreach ($array2 as $arr2)
   {
      echo $arr2[$arr2[index2][index2];
   }
}
```

I wrote a code but it tel me that index1 is undifined

Comment: We can't help you with these informations. You have to add more infos about what you have already tried and please format the code correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `foreach ($array1 as $index => $arr1) {...}`

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $val1 )
{
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $val2)
   {
      echo $arr2[$arr2[$key1][$key2]];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You current code makes no much sense (not to mention syntax error). First `index1` are undefined and also syntax you used is correct for constants nor variables. If you want to iterate over array and get the keys you need to do:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
```

so, guessing your intention:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $val1 )
{
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $val2)
   {
      echo $arr2[$arr2[$key1][$key2]];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanx i will try it and i will tell you

Comment: I tryed it it gives me more error please i posted my code can you tel me what is wrong and thanx

Comment: You seem to completely not understand what are you doing. Throwing random keywords (like you did with `endforeach` or by adding `()` to `echo` which is wrong) without knowing what they are for an where to use it leads you nowhere.

Comment: I am asking to know !! Thanx for help

Comment: You edited your question making it even more broken and also added some indices that were not here in the first place, which is based on your dataset you not mentioned. I answered your question about using indices. If you face another problem with your code now (and it is not the same you formerly asked) you must ask another question here.